# Run Python app once & give it input from a text file line-by-line in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a simple Python app that takes two inputs in separate lines and prints a result...

```py
def f(n, x):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    # print string n times
    print(n*x)

# number
n = int(input())
# string
x = input()
print(f(n, x))
```

Want to give inputs to the Python app from a `.txt` file and store the compiled **outputs** in another file (`output.txt`), the `inputs.txt` file contains these inputs:

```
3
a
4
b
5
c
⋮
0
```

The app should run once and then take each line as input...
How can I do that in Bash?
The **`output.txt`** should be like this:

```
aaa
bbbb
ccccc
```

P.S
I tried the below script but that was a disaster as the Python app runs again and only takes the first input!

```bash
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    python3 main.py | "$line"
done < inputs.txt >> output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Python script already iterates over its input line-by-line. You don't need to do much of anything in `bash` except provide the file to Python.

```
python3 main.py < inputs.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry but I've changed the question as that wasn't what I wanted to do...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to feed the values from Bash to Python, your python script needs to receive both the number and the character.
Have you tried reading lines 2 by 2 in your Bash loop?

Like

```bash
while read -r nbChar; read -r theChar [...]
```